# Is there a way to dynamically change the string in Text() of compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

For example, after some modification to the sample code snippet given in android developer's site

```
@Composable
fun ClickCounter(clicks: Int, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = onClick) {
        Text("I've been clicked $clicks times")
    }
}
```

it is possible to count the number of times a button is pressed and display this count by changing the string in the Text component in the UI. However this needs the user to physically press the button to get Text to change. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I would like to perform some calculation and somewhere else and when the result is ready, display it by updating Text (doing something like Text.setText("...") had I been using xml to generate the UI). How do I change the value of Text programmatically? Do any of the jetpack compose sample programs from google have a simple example of this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

composable functions need to have a `MutableState` in order to be  programmatically updated. It can be created from an observable (like LiveData or Flow) or by calling `mutableStateOf()`.

```
val text = mutableStateOf("text")
// or
val text = MutableStateFlow("text")

@Composable
fun MyText() {
    val myText by text
    // or
    val myText by text.collectAsState()
    Text(myText)
}
```

then you can update the value programmatically by updating the observable:

```
text.value = "other text"
```

Example

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val a = 10000L
    private val b = 1000L
    private val c = mutableStateOf(a)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(a, b) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                Log.d("MYLOG", "text updated programmatically")
                c.value = millisUntilFinished
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                c.value = 0
            }
        }
        timer.start()
        setContent { CountDown() }
    }

    @Composable
    fun CountDown() {
        val milliseconds by c
        val text = (milliseconds / 1000).toString()
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state)

Comment: What do I use as parameter when calling the MyText() function?

Comment: its just an example, you dont need to do that. I edited my answer

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have the computer in front of me to test this right now, but won't `val text by viewModel.text` cause an error now? `viewModel` is not declared

Comment: Do I create a viewModel object first from MyViewModel using this method? https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel

Comment: you can create it in the same way as before, or alternatively add this dependency `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha02` and call `viewModel<MyViewModel>()` directly from your composable

Comment: Is there a basic working example for this somewhere? Nothing I do is working. I can get a text label to update when I manually press a button a button on the UI, but I want the text label to display the value of a variable outside of a composable function, and update the display when that variable's value changes (outside of a composable function). Do they have a basic working example that does this?

Comment: have you tried `MutableStateFlow()` and `collectAsState()`?

Comment: yes everything I tried is causing an error in one place or another

Comment: do you know if one of the jetpack compose sample programs (one of these: https://github.com/android/compose-samples) has a basic working example for this?

Comment: can you show the error message? I havent seen these samples

Comment: I'll just share my MainActivity.kt file. Please have a look here: https://pastebin.com/yqASMJqM

Comment: May I am doing something wrong. I have commented all the parts that cause errors in the code I just shared above, but I have mentioned in the comment where there is a error. Specifically, it's at the point where I try to call my version of `viewModel.text.value = "other text"`

Comment: it would have been easier if you said you wanted to use a CountDownTimer

Comment: it's not necessarily a timer, but that's ok. The main problem is how do I make the text on the text field update programmatically

Comment: looks better now?

Comment: I am not at the computer anymore but I will check as soon as I get the opportunity. Thank you very much

Comment: This one worked. Thank you very much. Finally I have something I can build on

Comment: If I want to change the value of c inside the `CountDown()` composable, so that I can access the changed value from onCreate, can I do `c.value = 10` inside the composable function? Or is this the wrong way to think about this?

Comment: You can either do `c.value = 10` or, if you have already delegated it like this `var d by c`, then just do `d = 10`

Comment: Thank you very much. You have helped me a lot.

Comment: Thats the first example that actually helped, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In Compose the UI is immutable and there's no way to update it after it's been drawn but you can control the state of your UI.

In other word you haven't a method like `Text.setText("...")` but you can build composables functions that work on state and events.

[image]

For example you can use `mutableStateOf(value)`.
It creates a `MutableState`, which is an observable type in Compose. Any changes to its value will schedule recomposition of any composable functions that read that value.

You can use something like:

```
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }                        
    Button(onClick = { count++ }){
                Text("Add")
    }
    Text(text = "count: ${count}")
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture).

Comment: `Button(onClick ...` doesn't this mean the `count++` happens when the button is pressed? I want to avoid the user having to physically press something. Doesn't compose have any equivalent to `Label.setText("..")` of normal android programming?

Comment: @user13267It is just an example. Check the first line. You don't have a method like `setText`. You have to use a `mutableStateOf` or a `ViewModel`. Check also the provided link: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture

Answer (score 2):

same answer as Sinner but without the riddle

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val dyntext = mutableStateOf("")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        dyntext.value = "OK"

        setContent {
            ShowText()
        }

    }

    @Composable
    fun ShowText() {
        val dynt by dyntext
        Text(dynt)
    }
}
```